# Why does a derivative exist on a linear function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand that for a linear function, like $f(x)=3x$, the derivative at point $x$ would be $3$, but I don't understand why. The derivative's slope is equal to the tangent line's slope, but I was thinking that the tangent line shouldn't exist on a linear function since it would have to touch the graph at more than $1$ point in order to be parallel at a certain point. At point $(0,0)$ on the aforementioned $f(x)$, the derivative would have a constant line of $f'(x)=3$, but that's not perpendicular to the point.

Comment: Tangents don't have to touch at only one point.

Comment: And the derivative's *value* is equal to the tangent line's slope.

Comment: Being tangent is a local property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x$ is given by
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
In this case, we have
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{3(x + h) - 3x}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{3h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 3 = 3.$$
The limit exists, so the function is differentiable. Note how there's no implicit assumptions about how the linearisation intersects the function. There is no requirement that the tangent line intersects a function exactly once.